# Refreshing UITableView with new data from server

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm developing an app that fetchs info from an external API and stores it in an internal database. 
That info is shown in a UITableView.

The problem is the following: the second time I access to the ViewController I fetch data from the internal database and in background I request to the API for new data so when I get the response I need to refresh de UITableView (it is possible that some data received from the server already exists in the table).

Is it a good practice to call [tableView reloadData] or there is a more efficient way to update the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want animations or not. `[UITableView reloadData]` forces a complete reload with no animation. Your other option is to check what has been inserted/deleted/updated and use `[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`, `[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` and `[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`